# Prove that $F\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ such that its Fourier transform $\hat f$ equals zero in a neighborhood of zero.

Let $F$ be function such that $\hat F$ exists and

$$\hat f(x) =x\hat F(x),\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Prove that $F\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Any hints on how to prove that?

Thanks!

Comment: @Walace $\frac {\hat {f}(x)} x$ is in $L^{2}$ so $F$ exists as an $L^{2}$ function. The problem is to show that it is integrable.